# I get a blank page when I run this PHP/CakePHP code

Tags: php, cakephp

I get a blank page when I run this code I think its something to do with  where I close brackets:

```
<?php 

while($fabid==$fabric_ids[$cnt]['FabricOrdering']['fabric_id'] && $fabcolorid==$fabric_ids[$cnt]['FabricOrdering']['fabric_colour_id'] ){ 



?>


     <?php
                    $i = 0;

                       foreach ($orderEntry as $orderEntry1) {
                            $style = "";

                    if($$orderEntry1['FabricOrdering']['order_entry_headers_id'] && $orderEntry1['FabricOrdering']['finalized_state'] == OrderFinalized::FINALIZED_STATE_APPROVED){
                                $style = "background-color:#f2c7ef";

                            } else {
                                $style = "background-color:red";

                            }
                            ?>

                           <tr  id="<?php echo $new_row['FabricOrdering']['sbos_id'].'-'.$count.'-'.$order_seq.'_'.$fabcolorid;?>"style=" <?php echo $style;  ?>">
<?php }}?>
```

How to run `foreach` loop inside a `while` loop?

Comment: turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and tell us what you get?

Comment: well i debug it..first time it iterate through the foreach loops..and second time it goes to the if statement and keeps the value of first elements and apply to the all the table rows

Answer (score 2):

First in your code while loop with condition

```
while($fabid==$fabric_ids[$cnt]['FabricOrdering']['fabric_id'] && $fabcolorid==$fabric_ids[$cnt]['FabricOrdering']['fabric_colour_id'] ){
```

This condition always return true, so it might be go for infinite loop. Put some increment variable to false this condition.

Increment variable like `$cnt`.

```
if($$orderEntry1['FabricOrdering']['order_entry_headers_id']
```

Here $$ .

->set Dedug to 2 to check errors.

Comment: this is my sql query  SELECT order_finalizeds.order_entry_headers_id, order_finalizeds.finalized_state
FROM order_finalizeds
INNER JOIN fabric_orderings
ON order_finalizeds.order_entry_headers_id=fabric_orderings.order_entry_headers_id;    where should I change it?

Comment: first in cakephp to show errors set debug mode on in core.php file set debug to 2 with  Configure::write('debug', 2) so you can get exact error and problem .

Comment: first in cakephp to show errors set debug mode on in core.php file set debug to 2 with  Configure::write('debug', 2) so you can get exact error and problem .in your code foreach inside while loop foreach loop  iterate over arrays(records) so problem in while you have to set condition in while to break it .

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be the `$$` sign in your if condition. This would result in an runtime error, because you first use an array as an var name and then accessing the array, which isn't an array.

Just remove one `$` sign and it should work

Comment: nopr i removed it and check it still getting a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You've got trapped in an `infinite loop`.

In your `where` clause you're using this condition.

`$fabid==$fabric_ids[$cnt]['FabricOrdering']['fabric_id'] && $fabcolorid==$fabric_ids[$cnt]['FabricOrdering']['fabric_colour_id']`.

But nowhere inside the loop you're updating any of the variable. Gothrough your business logic and update the loop.

Comment: those variables are updating from the controller

Comment: but once you enter the loop, the values will not going to be changes and you'll never get back to the controller.

Comment: well i pass those values as an array

Comment: SELECT order_finalizeds.order_entry_headers_id, order_finalizeds.finalized_state
FROM order_finalizeds
INNER JOIN fabric_orderings
ON order_finalizeds.order_entry_headers_id=fabric_orderings.order_entry_headers_id;  this is my sql query where should I change the where clause?